# File "python", line 6, in <module> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python

```
 #while
 #import re
 A= float (input("Enter Number :"))
 B= float (input("Enter Number :"))

 if (any(x.isalpha() for x in A)):
 print ("No Letters Please")


C= (A/B)
print (C)
```

If i declare it as a string Line 6 works but then  Line 10 Does not Work

Comment: It's just what it says.  `A` is a float.  Floats aren't iterable.  You may want to capture the initial input first, check it, and then convert it with "float" and do your math.

Comment: Please add something that clear what you expected from your code. plus please correct the indentation of your code.

Comment: When you write `for x in y` you're telling python to loop through all the elements in `y`. This makes sense if `y` is something like a list with multiple elements. In your case, however, `y` is a float, which is just a single number. You can't iterate through a single number because there's only one there.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are iterable objects as they are lists of characters, essentially.
Numbers are not iterable.
Hence, you should do string iteration first and then convert to float for performing calculations with numbers.

Something like:

```
A = input("Enter Number :")
B = input("Enter Number :")

if (any(x.isalpha() for x in A)):
    print("No Letters Please")
C = (float(A) / float(B))
print(C)
```

Comment: But there's no reason to have the for loop at all. Why would you convert a single number to a string and loop through it when you can just look at the single number?

Comment: I was just commenting on the error with the code submitted. How to fix that error, not the approach.